# Store that sells video packages with access

Tags: ecommerce, video

I have a client that wants to add video subscriptions to their offering. They want people to be able to download as well as view on-site. I browsed around for something I thought might work that was already in use, but didn't see anything out there.

Is there something I have missed or is this something that will need to be built from scratch? I just didn't want to re-invent the wheel.  ;)

They will be able to purchase individual videos as well as packages or bricks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could totally do this with [CartThrob Pro w/Subscriptions](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/subscriptions).

Comment: Thanks Siebird. I've used CartThrob in the past. I don't know why I didn't look at subscriptions. I guess I could just host all the videos and packages in a channel with permissions and apply cart codes and packages for access. I was thinking about hosting the videos in a private channel on Vim or YT, but I don't think that will work for downloads especially.  ;)